# bootstrap modal delegate eventype syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap

```
var Modal = function (content, options) {
   this.options = options
   this.$element = $(content)
   .delegate('[data-dismiss="modal"]', 'click.dismiss.modal', $.proxy(this.hide, this))
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                        What does this mean?
}
```

I am quite fresh. I haven't seen this sort of syntax before. My guess is click event, on any attribute which contains a 'dismiss' and have value of 'modal'???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, what you are seeing is `Namespaced Events`. This is used extensively when you have multiple event handlers for a same event. See example below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/JcuAD/2/)

```
$('#test').on('click.a', function () {
    alert('A is clicked');
});

$('#test').on('click.b', function () {
    alert('B is clicked');
});

$('#unbindA').on('click', function () {
    $('#test').off('click.a');
});
```

In the above example it just demonstrates `unbind` but it can also be used for triggering a specific handler like `$('#test').trigger('click.a')`.

All the above is not possible when you just bind 'click' to both the handlers.

[**jQuery docs on Namespaced Events**](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events)

Comment: So in `.on('click.a'` the `.a` part is a name you can just make up, **correct?** It doesn't refer to anything in the framework, but is just a way to uniquely name your handler so you can reference it later in trigger/off/etc. ?

Comment: @AaronLS Yes, that is correct. You can read about it http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names

Answer (score 0):

To add to Vega's answer:

Calling `on()` (available since jQuery 1.7) or `delegate()` with the event `click.dismiss.modal` means to register a click handler that is fired when the `dismiss` or the `modal` namespaces are passed in the triggered event, or if `click` is called with no namespace.

The `modal` is not "nested" under `dismiss` (the syntax may be misleading), but they are treated as directly "attached" to `click`. That means `click.dismiss.modal` is equivalent to `click.modal.dismiss`.

Example:

```
$('#elem').on('click.dismiss.modal', function () {});
$('#elem').trigger('click.dismiss');  // handler is called
$('#elem').trigger('click.modal');  // handler is called
$('#elem').trigger('click');  // handler is called
$('#elem').trigger('click.abc');  // handler is NOT called
```

Note that `trigger()`, `unbind()`, and `off()` only accept one namespace.

```
$('#elem').off('click.dismiss');  // now the handler is just 'click.modal'
```

You can also unbind using `.dismiss` which will remove all events with that namespace (not just `click`). Triggering won't work with a namespace by itself; there must be an event name before the dot.